# Batch processing business flows

Tags: spring, spring-boot, batch-processing, activiti, camunda

I would like to ask about batch processing. I need to process 100 000 business flows which consist from these steps: generate PDF (asynchronous), send mail and upload document to archive system. I am considering to use activiti with spring boot (async service tasks) because I have control over failed jobs and I can easily retry them etc. I don't know if it's good idea to use activiti or camunda or some other tool.

[image: flow]

Comment: With camunda, you can use the engine-internal batch processing for custom jobs, checkout the camunda-bpm-custom-batch extension.

Comment: Another possibility is http://www.flowable.org/. Job processing has changed between Activiti5(Flowable5) <-> Flowable6. e.g. Deadletter queue and ++
And when you check the team http://www.flowable.org/team.html -> core activiti team moved to Flowable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a multi instance call activity. With the multi instance you can specify how of the call activity should be executed (in your case 100_000 times). The call activity will call your process model to archive the pdf. For each call (instance of the multi instance) you can define a variable which should be forwared to your called process, so it is possible to have a list of PDF file names in the main process and forward a name to each sub process. 
The main process could look like this:

[image]

Make sure that you make the multi instance async before to use the asynchronous continuation, otherwise this will not work with 100_000 instances.

The multi instance call activity could look like this:

```
<bpmn:callActivity id="Task_0fl5th9" name="archiving pdf" calledElement="archivePdf">
  <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_04xoo79</bpmn:incoming>
  <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_0036ezx</bpmn:outgoing>
  <bpmn:multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics camunda:asyncBefore="true" camunda:collection="pdfNames" camunda:elementVariable="pdfName">
    <bpmn:loopCardinality xsi:type="bpmn:tFormalExpression">100_000</bpmn:loopCardinality>
  </bpmn:multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
</bpmn:callActivity>
```

Comment: It seems that multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics does commit for each item. Is there any way to set commit count? And when I used camunda.bpm.job-execution.core-pool-size = 5 I noticed deadlock exceptions in log:
`### SQL: select * from ACT_RU_EXECUTION     where PROC_INST_ID_ = ?
### Cause: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 62) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.`

Comment: And I see the same deadlock on ACT_RU_JOB table 
`### SQL: select *     from ACT_RU_JOB J     where J.EXECUTION_ID_ = ?`